# Make ng-token-auth work with different browsers on same machine

Tags: angularjs, authentication

Currently, `ng-token-auth` works from only one browser at a time. As soon as I open the application in another browser, it asks me to `login` and the token in the first browser gets invalidated.

Is there a way around it?

I am testing my app in various browsers and I have to re-login for every request.

I am using `ng-token-auth`, along with `devise-token-auth` and `devise`. AFAIR, I have not changed any configurations and am as close as possible to the default.

I have configured $authProivder as :

```
$authProvider.configure({
    apiUrl: '',
    passwordResetSuccessUrl: baseUrl + '/#/passwordreset'
});
```

Comment: this seems to be a standardized feature of this sort of tokenized security;  browsers don't have access to each other's resources, and as such each browser needs to download a token, and token security dictates that only the *current* token is valid.  Aside from redesigning the token process to be something less secure (and a lot more work) by allowing and saving more than one token per user, this isn't something that can be solved on either the client or the server.

Comment: @Claies Thank You for responding. According to the documentation (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#token-header-format) , its possible to allow multiple sessions. The documentation for client parameter says "This enables the use of multiple simultaneous sessions on different clients". I tried setting it to Math.random(), but it still didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-token-auth`, by default, allows multiple simultaneous sessions from multiple devices. The solution for me, was to upgrade `ng-token-auth` and `devise-token-auth`.